# Exclude permission denied messages from find

Tags: grep, find, csh

In bash, I can redirect stderr using 2>&1 with the `find` command and pipe it to `grep` to remove any `Permission denied` messages. How do I do this in csh? I am getting the error message `Ambiguous output redirect`. I have already tried the syntax at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find), and it gives me the error described.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect stdout and stderr from csh script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849358/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-from-csh-script)

Comment: also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426440/stderr-redirection-methods

Comment: @Ben: Second link does not answer my question, nor is the answer having to do with find. And first link does not have to do with find nor does it only redirect stderr.

Comment: Both of them answer your question.

Comment: This isn't possible without writing to a file then grepping it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720246/redirect-stderr-to-stdout-in-c-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the link that @swdev posted in a comment above, the only way to do this by sending it to a file and then using `grep` on that file when you are in csh.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can use "! -executable -prune -o ..." to enter only accessible directories.